# Restart Firefox after crash fails

Tags: linux, firefox, crash

I'm using Firefox 31.0 on SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11.2, launched from a terminal window. Every now and then Firefox crashes, which in itself isn't too big of an issue as Firefox saves the session state regularly. However, after a crash attempting to restart Firefox (again via a terminal window) just fails without an error message after roughly one second. The only way I've found to get Firefox to work again is rebooting my machine. Does anyone know a solution to the problem to get Firefox working again without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Hey akid you can easily fix your problem by resetting your Firefox Borowser..
Before resetting let me clarify two things,

**1.** Firefox will save these things:

```
Bookmarks
Browsing history
Passwords
Open windows, tabs and tab groups
Cookies
Web form auto-fill information
Personal dictionary
```

**2.** These items and settings will be removed:

```
Extensions and themes, website-specific preferences, search engines, download history, DOM storage, security settings, download actions, plugin settings, toolbar customizations, user styles and social features will be removed.
```

For more help visit https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox/fix-problems .

Comment: According to the link you posted, resetting the browser is done via the GUI. This does not help me as Firefox does not start, and thus I cannot access this option.